# C++/WinRT - Implementing a property sheet handler

Tags: c++-winrt

C++/WinRT seems like an exciting advance in the state of the art, but I've not yet had call to use it, nor even update my years-old Windows SDK.   Before I do, perhaps someone can advise me.

I'd like to implement a shell extension property sheet handler, `IShellExtInit` and `IShellPropSheetExt`, and thought that might be something to do in C++/WinRT.   Will the new language features and COM projections simplify the task?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-coclasses) is the doc for authoring COM components with C++/WinRT.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.   But will I need to do my own declspecs etc, or is that now addressed for shell interfaces by something machine generated?   I'm familiar with managed code interop, it's just been a pain to get working in the shell.

Comment: It seems that you need to implement the interfaces, maybe `IShellExtInit` and `IShellPropSheetExt`, while others are up to you.

Comment: Thanks @Berrysoft, I mentioned those specific interfaces in the question.